# Maximum character count for business capability survey questions and answers

Tags: surveys

I am building an online/mobile binary business survey with 15 questions and 5 multiple choice answers for each. Each answer lists a business capability based on the company's level of maturity. Do you have any data or anecdotes to support the maximum character count recommended for each question and each answer/capability, in order for an executive to read through and select one or more answers within 20 minutes? Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

### Maybe you can use chat GPT to resolve it. Hope it would be useful :)

And I attach the reasoning as someone seemed showing strong objection. I respect the commenter's point too.

But in using chat-GPT, which is based on LLM models, I'm also getting a lot help when refining my words. So I think it might be somewhat helpful to find the better length of the questions for your query. Agree that GPT might not be the best solution for finding deeper insights, what to ask and etc, but it has been useful to refine words and condense wordy sentences.

Comment: Even if chatGPT was capable of producing a good, well reasoned result here, it's very unhelpful to just point to the bot. Just like external links, the answer may change over time or the service may shut down.